# Show modal on click from radio button input

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button, show-hide

I have two radio buttons. Yes and No. For yes, on click it will show a download button underneath which works fine with the current HTML and Javascript. Now when you select the "No" radio button, I want it to display a modal with information. I already have the modal implemented and working as a separate button, but I haven't found any solutions to show the modal upon radio button input for no.

Here is the current Javascript that I have for show/hide from radio button input for divs.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("input[name$='bn']").click(function(){
      var radio_value = $(this).val();
      if(radio_value=='0') {
        $("#contact").fadeIn("slow");
        $("#dlcert").fadeOut("slow");
       }
      else if(radio_value=='1') {
        $("#dlcert").fadeIn("slow");
        $("#contact").fadeOut("slow");
        }
      });
      $('[name="bn"]:checked').trigger('click');
    });
```

**[jSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/acfpho/pd86o68u/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `$('#myModal').modal('show');` if the input no is checked

```
$('input[name="bn"]').change(function() {
   if($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).val() == '0') {
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
   }
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/IA7medd/pd86o68u/2/

Comment: You are a god amongst men. THANK YOU!! Essentially this is just adding on to the original function that shows/hides for each of the radio buttons right?

Comment: Yes you can add it to the original function but in this case it will be opened at every click on the input, but my function work only on change so if the input is already checked, it will not open the modal.

and you are welcome :)